# using C# interface to create a Manager class that implementing a singleton pattern, but the child manager class does not have a singleton pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, interface, singleton

I am creating a `Manager` class that implements singleton patterns with C# interface.

I came up with a structure to apply a singleton pattern to the `Manager` class, inherit it to my children, and extend the functionality.
However, if I try to access it from the other class, I can only access the `Manager` class.

I think I need to modify the code or structure, what should I do?

**ISingleton.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface ISingleton<T> where T : class
{
    void SetSingleton(T _classType, GameObject _obj);
    T GetInstance();
}
```

**Singleton.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour , ISingleton<T> where T: class
{
    public static T instance = default;
    public void SetSingleton(T _class, GameObject _obj)
    {
        if (instance is null) instance = _class;
        else if(instance.Equals(_class))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Unexpected Instancing Singleton Occuired! from " + gameObject.name);
            Destroy(_obj);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(_obj);
    }
    public T GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Manager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Manager : Singleton<Manager>,IManager
{
    public int data;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        SetSingleton(this,this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**GameManager**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : Manager
{
    public int HP,point;
    protected override void Awake()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        SetSingleton(this, this.gameObject);
    }

    private void StartGame() => print("GameStart");
    private void PauseGame() => print("Game Paused");
    private void QuitGame() => Application.Quit();
}
```

**Below is the rough structure of my code.**

[image: Singleton interface oriented Manager]

Comment: You can't really force the singleton pattern by using an interface since there's nothing stopping someone from adding in a constructor that lets them create a new instance. Also, the `GetInstance` method would need to be `static` which means it cannot form part of the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Manager` class derives from `Singleton<Manager>`, which provides a method to get an instance of `Manager`, `Singleton<Manager>.GetInstance()`. Your `GameManager` now inherits from `Manager` and with that from `Singleton<Manager>`.

As you already do in `GameManager.Initialize()`, you can set the manager singleton with `SetSingleton`, and it accepts the `GameManager` as argument, because it expects a `Manager`, which your `GameManager` ist.

But your `GameManager` still only implements `Singleton<Manager>`, meaning the `GetInstance()` method can only return a `Manager`, not a `GameManager`, although the manager you get back is actually your `GameManager`. You could cast that now to a `GameManager` and it would work, although that would be a rather unclean solution.

That said: I think trying to enforce a singleton pattern via interface is not a clean solution, as was pointed out in comments already. If you want to work with singleton manager instances, I would advise you to look into dependency injection. For Unity I can highly recommend [Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject). If you never worked with DI before it takes a moment to get used to, but used correctly it makes your code cleaner; I for one would not want to miss it in my projects.